# Filter IQueryable<dynamic> given user input

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, filtering

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
//Create Connection.
NMBSReportViewer.Models.SchoolEntities db = new NMBSReportViewer.Models.SchoolEntities();

//Get the Data Using the Report's Stored QueryString.
String QueryString = report.Query; //"SELECT VALUE c FROM SchoolEntities.Courses AS c WHERE c.Credits > 0";
IQueryable<dynamic> data = db.CreateQuery<dynamic>(QueryString);

//Given String FieldName, String Operator, & String Value, from user, Filter the Above dataset.
data.Where(c => c.'FieldName' 'Operator' 'Value');
```

I'm assuming there's nothing like I have above, but is there a way to achieve the same end result?
I am going to have Dropdownlists of the Fields and operators for the user and then they will input a value they want in a textbox for the three values, so the FieldName is should always be a viable field in the set.

Is there a way in LINQ to do such a thing? 
If there isn't a way to do that...
Is there a way to create an IQueryable with a static type of "SchoolEntities.Course" given just the string?

Comment: Why not simply create an Expression dynamically to supply to the Where clause?

Comment: Do you mean like this?

http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/2/18/aspnet-mvc-generic-filtering-based-on-expressions

If so, it's because idk how to do it since you can't do typeof(dynamic).

Sorry, I am very new to all of this.

Comment: I think I misunderstood then. If you're looking to hand dynamic entities; that is entities not known at compile time, then Entity Framework is probably not what you want to be using.

Comment: So simply put I can't make the application not need to be redeployed everytime and use entity?
I guess my boss and I were mistaken then. I think I found what it is I need to do.

I'm not really sure on protocol for this, Do I delete the question or do I answer it myself? Since my answer isn't entirely answering the question I asked, at least not directly, considering the way I asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the Confusion, I guess Entity Framework wasn't an option after all.

In the end I guess I'll have to use this approach in order to maintain the freedom from redeploying the project everytime the database gains or loses a table.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Connection String
String ConnectionString = @"Data Source = localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = School; Trusted_Connection=True;";

//Create the Connection
SqlConnection DbConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

//Open the Connection
DbConn.Open();

//Query String
String QueryString = "SELECT * FROM COURSE";

//Create the SqlCommand Object
SqlCommand QueryCommand = new SqlCommand(QueryString, DbConn);

//Use the SqlCommand to create the DataReader Object.
SqlDataReader QueryCommandReader = QueryCommand.ExecuteReader();

//Create the Datatable.
DataTable DataT = new DataTable();

//Load the Data into the Table.
DataT.Load(QueryCommandReader);

//Get the User Input
String Expression = "Credits > 3";

//Create DataRows and Filter Table.
List<DataRow> FilteredData = new List<DataRow>();
FilteredData = DataT.Select(Expression).ToList();
}
```

Thank you for the help and information. Sorry it wasn't entirely a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
IQueryable<Course> data = db.CreateQuery<Course>(QueryString);
```

You could also query the Course entity like so:

```
IQueryable<Course> data  = db.Course.Where(c => c.Credits > 0 && c.Name == "Bob");
```

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is I need for the program I'm making to not rely on the Entity models because my boss wants it in a way so we don't have to redeploy the Report Viewing program everytime a table is added to the database. And from my understanding having IQueryable<Course> would make it to where we would have to do that.

Comment: if you don't depend on Entity models, then you're at least depending on View Models. Which -- need to be mapped to/from Entity models. Unless I'm missing something obvious. (very likely!)

Comment: @Shelby115 If you don't want to use entity models at all then you're likely better off just not using a LINQ query provider in the first place.  I'm sure it's *possible*, if you work hard enough, but most of its benefits won't apply so you won't really gain much from it.

Comment: Is this possible without using Entity at all?
Given the Connection String and Query String Fetch the data as some collection and then easily filter it?
Sorry if this is dumb question I'm just really new to both Web and Database applications so I feel a bit overwhelmed here at work.

Comment: It is possible to not use Entity at all; you could use a custom written business class, Courses.cs, that implements the various features you want, or you could use a simple data layer that returns a DataTable where you do some filtering and sorting either in the codebehind or via datagridview. There are + and - to all of these approaches. Entity is premade business and data layer that handles everything but introduces some dependencies. Custom business layers would require the most work, but would give many benefits of Entity. No bus layer would be simple to code but cost most maintenance.